# Save entities with virtual columns in gorm grails

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, virtual-column

So , in my application i have a entity with a virtual column.
The column takes values depending on what i save in another column.

On save i have the following error:

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns

This is because i am sending a null value on that field.

Does anybody know how to map a virtual column in gorm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [extended GORM mappings](http://grails.org/plugin/extended-gorm-mappings) plugins allows you to mark individual columns to be excluded from inserts and updates.

Example:

```
static mapping = {
    readOnlyColumn updateable: false, insertable: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails derived properties might provide the functionality you need.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties